# How can I get a Store in a Controller to bind data to a View?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Controller with a handler onLogin() that gets called after a successful log in request:

```
Ext.define('AddressBook.controller.Application', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
...
onLogin: function(form, record) {
    var editButton = this.getEditButton();

    if (!this.showContact) {
        this.showContact = Ext.create('AddressBook.view.contact.Show');
    }

    //how to get this store?
    var store = getContactsStore();
    //how to get the data in the store or should I get the model?
    this.showContacts.updateDataProvider(store.array);

    // Push the show contact view into the navigation view
    this.getMain().push(this.showContact);
},
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
Ext.getStore('storeId')
```

it will give you store's object

Comment: But how and where do I define the 'storeId'? xtype won't do as I tried.

Comment: soterId is config of store,so you can define in store like storeId:'testStore'

Comment: thx. I found out that the name of the store will do too. So if the store is called Contacts.js, you can do: Ext.getStore("Contacts");